# Different utf8 encodings?

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I`ve a small issue with utf8 encoding.
the word i try to encode is "kühl". 
So it has a special character in it.

When i encode this string with utf8 in the first file i get:

kÃ¼hl

When i encode this string with utf8 in the second file i get:

kuÌ�hl

With php utf8_encode() i always get the first one (kÃ¼hl) as an output, but i would need the second one as output (kuÌ�hl).

mb_detect_encoding tells me for both it is "UTF-8", so this does not really help.

do you have any ideas to get the second one as output?
thanks in advance!

Comment: When I check kÃ¼hl in notepad++ and choose UTF-8, its ok. The second one seems to be strange.

Comment: any idea what the second one could be? i don t understand why mb_detect_encoding tells me it is also UTF-8

Comment: I assume your script files are saved using different character encodings – so your are not actually UTF8-encoding the same sequence of bytes in those two cases, but different ones.

Comment: also thought so, but that`s not the problem. any idea which encoding the second one could be?

Comment: In "kuÌ�hl", I'm seeing a U+00CC "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH GRAVE" followed by a U+FFFD "REPLACEMENT CHARACTER"; the latter looks like a white question mark in a black diamond. Whatever data you had in your string, some of it was lost on the way to my browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one encoding called UTF-8 but there are multiple ways to represent some glyphs in Unicode.  [U+00FC](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fc/index.htm) is the Latin-1 compatibility single-glyph precomposed ü which displays as kÃ¼hl in Latin-1 whereas <del>off the top of my head</del> kuÌ�hl looks like a fully decomposed expression of the same character, i.e. [U+0075](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/75/index.htm) (u) followed by [U+0308](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0308/index.htm) (combining diaeresis).  See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization

```
vbvntv$ perl -CSD -le 'print "ku\x{0308}hl"' | iconv -f latin1 -t utf8
kuÌ�hl
vbvntv$ perl -CSD -le 'print "ku\x{0308}hl"' | xxd
0000000: 6b75 cc88 686c 0a                   ku..hl.
```

0x88 is not a valid character in Latin-1 so (in my browser) it displays as an "invalid character" placeholder (black diamond with a white question mark in it) whereas others might see something else, or nothing at all.

Apparently you could use [`class.normalize`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) to convert between these two forms in PHP:

```
$normalized = Normalizer::normalize($input, Normalizer::FORM_D);
```

By the by, viewing UTF8 as Latin-1 and copy/pasting the representation as if it was actual real text is capricious at best.  If you have character encoding questions, the actual bytes (for example, in hex) is the only portable, understandable way to express what you have.  How your computer renders it is unpredictable in many scenarios, especially when the encoding is problematic or unknown.  I have stuck with the presentation you used in your question, but if you have additional questions, take care to articulate the problem unambiguously.

Comment: I want upvotes for the back-asswards approach of feeding UTF-8 to `iconv` and telling it to convert Latin-1 to UTF-8 in order to see the "Latin-1" representation in my UTF-8 terminal.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but is this an NFC vs NFD problem? While this answer is very descriptive it hasn't really answered the question that the OP has asked, which was how to get it in NFD.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ Thanks for pointing that out! Added a snippet of PHP to do that.

Answer (score 0):

utf8_encode, despite it's name, does not magically encode into UTF-8.

It will only work, if your source is ISO-8559-1, also known as latin-1.

If your source was already UTF-8 or any other encoding it will output broken data.